# How can I populate an array of dynamic references to multiple collections?

Tags: mongoose, populate

I am trying to figure out how mongoose's populate works when it comes to an array of dynamic references to multiple other collections.

I have a User schema. One of my keys is itemsBorrowed. This is supposed to be an array of documents from two other collections (OfferedItem and RequestedItem).

At the moment this ItemsBorrowed array contains the IDs of those items that the user has borrowed (either the ID of an OfferedItem or a RequestedItem). I want to populate this array so that instead of a plain ID, I get the whole document.

This is what my schema looks like at the moment:

```
//itemsBorrowed array can be populated either by OfferedItem or by RequestedItem.
//If the requested item is requested by the user, then the RequestedItem should be added to the array.
//If the offered item is borrowed by the user, then the OfferedItem should be added to the array.

        itemsBorrowed: [{ 
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            refPath: 'itemsBorrowedModel'
        }], 
        itemsBorrowedModel: {         
            type: String,
            enum: ['OfferedItem', 'RequestedItem']
        },
```

As I've already said, this ItemsBorrowed array currently contains the IDs of those items that the user has borrowed (either the ID of an OfferedItem or a RequestedItem). I want to populate this array so that instead of a plain ID, I get the whole document. According to the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref), I have to call the populate method on the query and the array should get populated with documents instead of IDs. So this is what I am doing:

```
//Get specific user by id
export const getUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id))
    return res.status(404).send(`No user with id: ${id}`);
  try {
    const user = await userModel.findById(id).populate('itemsBorrowed');
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

But it doesn't work, I still only get an array of IDs instead of an array of documents. Could anyone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you!